# Dynamically refreshing CUBEVALUE

Tags: excel, vba, powerpivot

Trying to dynamically refresh a bunch of CUBEVALUE functions to build a report. One of the dimensions of CUBEVALUE refers to an Excel validation list.

What I am trying to do is loop (via VBA) over the elements of the validation list, have Excel refresh and recalculate the CUBEVALUES so I can cut and paste these values (and a couple of charts) below to do it all again.

The problem is CUBEVALUE is being copied when "GETTING DATA..." is displayed and I want to wait for the data to be good before I copy it.

Some idea on how better to do this would be appreciated.

Tried Application.Wait and Sleep but even with 20 second delays it still fails

```
Set inputRange = Evaluate(Range("C1").Validation.Formula1)
For Each c In inputRange
    Range("C1").Value = c.Value

        newHour = Hour(Now())
        newMinute = Minute(Now())
        newSecond = Second(Now()) + 20
        waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
        Application.Wait waitTime

    Range("A22:A42").EntireRow.Insert
    Range("A3:A20").EntireRow.Copy

    Range("A3").Offset(21, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("A3").Offset(21, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("shpGraphs")).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A29").Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (PNG)", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

C1 is used in D1

```
=IF(C1="All","[Table1].[Location].[All]","[Table1].[Location].[All].["&C1&"]")
```

which is used in a CubeValue function (8 per loop) e.g.

```
=CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel",$D$1,"[Measures].[Number of Cars]")
```

Trying to get Excel to "wait" after the Range("C1").Value = c.Value line long enough before the rest of the code runs.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be to have a loop which only breaks once your cell's value does not equal "GETTING DATA...".  Then have a delay, and reassignment of value.

E.g. something like the below pseudo code to handle the wait.

```
Loop (check if value <> "GETTING DATA..." )
   Delay of x time
   value = cell value
End Loop
Move to Next Cell
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have used in my workbook:

```
Sub RefreshAll_WaitForCubeCalc()
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
End Sub
```